# Typescript cannot invoke expression whost type lacks a call signature

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm aware there are similar questions but I havent found anything that answers my question so far Im just trying to create a simple function in my angular application

app.component.ts

```
formClick() {

    const formContainer = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.form-container');
    const spinner = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.loading-spinner');
    const form = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.email-form');

    form.style.display = 'none';
    spinner.style.display = 'block';

    setTimeout(function(){
       spinner.style.display = 'none';
       formContainer.innerHTML('<h1>Thanks! We will get back to you shortly</h1>')
    }, 1000);
}
```

but im getting an error on my `formContainer.innerHTML` that says

`[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures.
(property) Element.innerHtml: string`

I'm not sure what this means, any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: innerHTML is not a function. You assign to it.

Comment: @unional yes thank you I'm an idiot haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is this line `formContainer.innerHTML('<h1>Thanks! We will get back to you shortly</h1>')`.

It should be `formContainer.innerHTML = '<h1>Thanks! We will get back to you shortly</h1>'`